# Convert Time value into Integer in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to `convert` `Time` value into `integer` value .

For E.g:  If the `time` value is `'07:00 PM'` I need to `convert` it into `19`.

I have tried below query to do this.

```
select CAST(substring(CONVERT(varchar,convert(smalldatetime,'07:00 PM'),114), 1,2) as int) as VALUE
```

It returns me the desired output. But it's taking too much time in case of `big transactions`. Can anyone suggest me an alternative solution ( a simple one perhaps)?

I can't use  `datepart(hour, 'timevalue')`. Because there are data's with time value  `'00:00 AM'`and`'00:00 PM'`which through's conversion error`.`In This case I need to return the value as `0`.`

Comment: Are your time values stored as text?  Do they always follow the format: hh:mm AM/PM?

Comment: values stored a varchar. yes they follow the format

Comment: I've posted a working solution below.  Should also point out that 00:00 PM is an invalid time, which is the cause of your conversion error.  00:00 AM is valid (midnight).  00:00 PM does not exist.

Comment: @destination-data thanks for pointing this out. 00:00 PM is an invalid time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to extract the hour from the time.  Use `datepart()`:

```
select datepart(hour, timecol)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will not work with '00:00 PM' or '00:00 AM'

Comment: @bmsqldev . . . I'm not sure what you mean by that.  SQL Server has well defined formats for time constants, and `datepart()` works on `time` values.  Perhaps it doesn't do what you expect, but it does extract the proper hour from the time as specified by the language.

Answer (score 2):

By using DATEPART() ...

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME =  N'07:00 PM'

SELECT DATEPART(hh, @DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will not work with '00:00 PM' or '00:00 AM'

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @test_date DATETIME

SET @test_date = N'07:00 PM'

SELECT DATEPART(hh, @test_date)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will not work with '00:00 PM' or '00:00 AM'

Comment: In this case you can simply omit AM or PM note.

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes that:

A) You are storing the times as a string.

B) The format **is always** HH:MM AM/PM.

Assumptions in data can be a very dangerous thing.  Especially with large datasets that could contain fringe values.  If at all possible I would recommend stores times as [TIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb677243.aspx).  This will allow you to use the many date/time functions within SQL Server.  It will also limit the values than can be entered.

This examples uses the following sample data:

Sample Data

```
/* Example uses data below.
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        TimeValue VARCHAR(8)
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        TimeValue
    )
VALUES    
    ('00:00 AM'),
    ('07:00 AM'),
    ('07:00 PM')
;
```

Because the format is fixed we can rely on the first 2 characters to contain the hour, and the last two to tell us if we are dealing with AM or PM.

Example

```
/* Using LEFT and RIGHT to read the text value.
 */
SELECT
    TimeValue,        
    LEFT(TimeValue, 2) + CASE WHEN RIGHT(TimeValue, 2) = 'PM' THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
FROM
    @Sample
;
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the 12 HR format to 24 HR format as:

```
convert(char(5),cast('07:00 PM' as datetime),108)
```

and then use the [DatePart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function as:

```
select datepart(hour,
 convert(char(5),cast('07:00 PM' as datetime),108) )
```